# unable to use the data from d3.csv() outside of the .get clause

Tags: json, csv, d3.js

I can read some data from a csv with d3. It works fine.

```
        d3.csv("myfile.csv")
          .get(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
```

If I execute this, it prints the data to the console in the expected way. It even recognizes the column headers.  But the problem is I'm trying to read a number of csv and json files. Nesting them is ugly, tedious and error prone.  So I tried this:

```
        var something;

        d3.csv("myfile.csv")
          .get(function(data) {
            something = data;
          });

        console.log(something);
```

The problem is that "something" doesn't have the expected value any more.  I figure this has got to be a common thing. How is the handled? (I'm using d3 4.2.8)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work for you?

```
const doSomething = data => {
  console.log(data);
}

d3.csv("myfile.csv").get(doSomething);
```

Comment: I'll give that a try later today.  I finally decided to bite the bullet so to speak and just nest the inputs.  It's not too bad, if I just indent all the reads / gets at the same level.  But if this works, I'll surely switch. tx

Comment: Holy Moses! It worked!  The syntax and semantics are strange to me, but I can live with it.
Still, it's not doing what I want - or what I thought I wanted.  I had intended to read in several csvs ... and keep them all existing at the same time and in the same space and work with them as I need to later.  This solution moves the problem to doSomething().